# Excel file creation very slow

Tags: php, arrays, excel

My application reads a cvs file and it takes 5 minutes to create an excel file. It is very slow.

I already tried to set  `$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false)`, but it doesn't solve the problem.

```
   for ($i = 0; $i <$numberOfUsers; $i ++) {
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)         
        ->setCellValue('A' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[0]])
        ->setCellValue('B' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[1]])
        ->setCellValue('C' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[2]])
        ->setCellValue('D' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[3]])
        ->setCellValue('E' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[4]])
        ->setCellValue('F' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[5]])
        ->setCellValue('G' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[6]])
        ->setCellValue('H' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[7]])
        ->setCellValue('I' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[8]])
        ->setCellValue('J' . (string) ($i + $celIndex), $data[$i][$tempLabels[9]]);
    }
```

Comment: How big of files are you working with?

Comment: @JasonK 1,135 KB

Comment: That should not be a problem.  You didn't share much of your code. I wold go through the code and make sure you don't have some other loop causing a problem.